# Z3 adding new variables during execution

Tags: z3

I'm trying to add a new feature to Z3.
This feature requires me to add new slack variables during execution and after pre-proccessing.
I could not find a proper way to this and I fear that attempting to force it by adding a new column will "break" the solver.

Is there a common recommended way to do that?

Thanks,
Omer

Answer (score 2):

You can find an example in the file `src/smt/theory_arith_int.h`, method: `mk_gomory_cut`.
In the end of this method, a new polynomial constraint is created, and stored in the variable `bound`. Then, the following piece of code is used to "internalize" the constraint:

```
    literal l     = null_literal;
    context & ctx = get_context();
    ctx.internalize(bound, true);
    l = ctx.get_literal(bound);
```

The method `internalize` will callback theory_arith, and a new slack is created.
Remark: the method `internalize` assumes the polynomial constraint stored in `bound` is in simplified form.